# D3 Donut Chart - Remove 0% label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having difficulty filtering out a 0% label on one of my D3 donut charts. I've tried using .filter. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a data set that creates 9 donut charts (win percentages in conference for 9 college teams). One of the teams hasn't won a single conference match, therefore they have 0%.

Here is my JS for the labels. I want to show all of my data except for the one with 0.

```
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(function (d) { return pie(d.percent); })
  .enter().append("g");

  g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "arcLabel")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.percent.toFixed(1) + "%" ; });
```

Is this an issue with putting the filter in the right place here or when I call my data? Here are the lines that call my data.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;



color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Team" && key !=="Record"; } ));

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.percent = color.domain().map(function(Team) {
  return {Team: Team, percent: +d[Team], };
});
});

//rest of the code for my charts here
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this on the text() of "text" element:

```
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.percent == 0 ? "" : d.data.percent.toFixed(1) + "%" ; });
```

check if you have a numeric 0 or a "0" as a string in your data

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I'm new to D3 and JS. Can you explain what is going on in this line of code?

Comment: this is JS fix, and its ?: operator which is equivalent of if else block. It checks if data.percent is 0 and aoccrdingly returns an empty string "" or the % value.